# Am I able to make an AJAX call to a specific function within a PHP file from a JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a Javascript function that pulls in the users latitude/longitude and stores it in an array for later use.  What I'm trying to do is take the users latitude/longitude and run a distance comparison to several other latitude/longitudes which are stored in a database.  What I'm trying to do, and I could be thinking about this all wrong, is make a call with AJAX within that Javascript, to a specific function within a PHP file (the function pulls just the latitude/longitude of each related store from the database).  Normally, this should be easy, but there are multiple functions within the PHP file so I'm wondering if this can even be accomplished this way.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.  I'm still new to all of this so your patience is appreciated.

This is the code I have so far (I'm brand new to AJAX so I don't have any AJAX code written yet):

```
function userPosition() {

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  currentPos.push(lat, lng);

  }, function(error) {
    alert('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
    // error.code can be:
    //   0: unknown error
    //   1: permission denied
    //   2: position unavailable (error response from location provider)
    //   3: timed out
  });
};
```

Here's the code within the PHP file:

```
    public function get_closest_location() {
    $addresses = array();
    $i = 0;
    //Get primary address
    $addresses[$i]['lat'] = $this->dealer_info['lat_1'];
    $addresses[$i]['lng'] = $this->dealer_info['lng_1'];

    //Get Dealer Addresses
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->gdp_dealers_addresses WHERE dealerId = %d", $this->dealer_info['dealer_id'] ), ARRAY_A );

    foreach($results as $res){
        $i++;
        $addresses[$i]['lat'] = $res['lat'];
        $addresses[$i]['lng'] = $res['lng'];

    }

    return $addresses;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are able to do it. But how to do it is too broad of a question. You need to say what your issue is and maybe provide some code.

Comment: Do you have an example you could possibly provide?  I'm completely lost and haven't found anything online.

Comment: Without knowing what your issue is, it is hard to give you exact pointers.

Comment: Can't you pass a POST or GET parameter to the phpscript? This would clean things up, and you can easily detect the $_POST parameter and return the result of the function call

Comment: I edited my comment above to include the code I have.  Again, I'm brand new to AJAX so I'm at a loss as how to proceed.  Sorry.

Comment: I have both the JS and PHP code above

Comment: You could check how [WordPress does ajax](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php), which is pretty much exactly what you're describing.

Comment: A quick recap on using SO. If an answer is helpful, give it an upvote (up arrow). If it solves your problem, mark it as correct (tick) To make comments, use the comment box - **dont** make a comment using the answer box. You should delete the (non) answer you just made

Comment: deleted.  Thanks for the heads up Steve.

Comment: Josh RE: Your "How do I get better at asking questions" question. Read these and apply them, then your questions will get better!  [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly.  I'll take a look at those now.  I'm not trying to be "that guy" on this forum so I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes and No, so the solution is not totally straight forward

As you can only get AJAX to directly run a PHP script and not a function inside it, all you need to do is add some information to the POST data that you send to the PHP script to tell it what function within your PHP library you want to run.

So you add something like this to the posted variables

```
var params  = {.........};

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { toRun: 'userPosition', anyData: params }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
});
```

Then in your PHP that is the first thing you test for

```
<?php

     // check for existance of all required post variables
     switch ($POST['toRun']) {

     case : 'userPosition'
         // get any other parameters out of POST array you may need
         $params = array(.....);
         userPosition();
         break;

     case : 'otherFunction'
        ...
        ...

     default :
        echo 'Huston we have a problem';
```

This is a basic outline and you will of course have to add some more code to look after passing back data, but this is the basic outline
         }

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you pass a GET parameter to the php script. This would look as follows:

javascript:

```
$.post( "script.php?action=userPosition", { lat: "2.0123123", long: "2.0319239123" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

append this to your php file:

```
if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "userPosition") {   
    echo get_closest_location($_POST["lat"], $_POST["long"]);
    exit;
}
```

you would need to modify the arguments of the php function obviously, but then this would be all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Php essentially runs from top to bottom. Calling the file ftom the browser does just that.
If the file contains function definitions, but no calling code, nothing will be run.

To handle your problem, you need to:

1. Identify the function to be called
2. Check it is an allowed function, to avoid malichious code injection
3. Call the function

To do that, you can send the required function as a get parameter, check it against a whitelist, and call it:

```
//example.php

function somefunc(){}
function anotherfunc(){}
function privatefunc(){}

function onLoad(){
    $func = isset($_GET['func']) ? $_GET['func'] : false;
    $allowed = ['somefunc','anotherfunc'];
    if(in_array($func, $allowed){
        call_user_func($func);
    }
}
//call onload function when script is executed
onLoad();
```

To call a function you would use the correct query string in your ajax request, eg `/example.php?func=somefunc`

Comment: To follow on, what you will have made is a rudimentary router. I would highly recommend you google for a nice modern php microframework (slim, silex, fatfreephp) that will have a far more robust implementation, plus a whole lot more. Reinventing the wheel is rarely a good idea. Writing raw php often falls into that category